# Extenção pgsql Não carrega no PHP7.x

Tags: postgresql, apache, php-7, windows-10

Estou mudando do PHP5 para o PHP7 no windows 10 (maquina desenvolvimento), todas as minhas configurações subiram de boa, MySQL, Firebird, PDO MySQL, PDO PGSQL, mas o bendito PGSL Nativo não sobe, já habilitei a linha "extension=pgsql" e conferi as dlls, tudo no lugar, tanto é que no php5 funciona.

Já troquei DLLs, já testei varias coisas e nada.

Iniciei o apache na linha de comando do para ver se dava algum erro, então ele me mostrou um erro na dll php_pgsql.dll, fui lá e troquei a dll por uma versao mais nova, ele para de dar o erro, inicia o apache, mas o modulo do pgsql nativo não carrega, só os PDOs da vida.

Tem alguma forma de iniciar o PHP em modo debug pra ver onde está o erro?

Uma curiosidade, tenho um servidor Ubuntu com PHP7 rodando, olhando no php.ini as linhas das extensões acima estão comentadas, mas o phpinfo mostra tudo ativo, tem alguma configuração que libera tudo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Solução que encontrei

Adicionar essa linha no httpd.conf

LoadFile "C:/Program Files (x86)/PHP/libpq.dll"

Forçando o apache a usar a dll que esta no php para ficar compativel com a php_pgsql.dll